# Antenna tuning for a multi-band antenna

Tags: rf, antenna, frequency, tuning

I have a PCB antenna that supports multiple band antenna.

https://www.johansontechnology.com/datasheets/0830AT54A2200/0830AT54A2200.pdf

We also have a tune circuit before the antenna as recommended by thevantenna manufacturer.

[image]

So the question is: through the tune circuit we can tune the antenna to a single band, and to tune to another band we need to tune the antenna again. So what is the purpose of the antenna being multiple-band, since every band needs a different tune circuit, a different BOM, so high cost.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to build up an evaluation model of your design, tune the L and C values, and put those in the production BOM. You could design the match circuit to hit both bands of the antenna but you aren't going to get as great performance of either.

Answer (score 0):

The “single” antenna does not have multiple bands as far as what the data sheet says; there are 4 antennas offered in the data sheet all operable in slightly different bands. Read carefully the data sheet and note the subtle difference between the four part numbers.

This means that you need a different BoM for each band anyway.

Comment: Datasheet state four eval board part only. but the antenna is only part number. its support multband as datasheet first page claim'LTE Multi-Band Ceramic Antenna, SMD. Ideal for Cellular, IoT, CAT M1,
and NB (Narrow Band) Applications
"

Comment: So what might be the reason that there are four evaluation boards rather than one evaluation board with matching components that suit all the bands?